# Webpack how to export something when entry is an array

Tags: javascript, webpack

If I do the normal thing and have a string path, the default export works:

```
entry: {
  'someExportName': './src/index.js'
}
```

However I'm trying to refactor a legacy project which exports multiple css files, one of them has the same name as the JS file:

```
entry: {
  'someExportName': ['./src/index.js', './src/themes/default.less'],
  'someExportName.nonDefaultTheme': './src/themes/nonDefaultTheme.less',
}
```

The problem is that if I use an array, even though I get `someExportName.js` and `someExportName.css`, Webpack no longer knows what the default export of the library should be. In the generated code it goes from:

```
return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./src/index.js");
```

To:

```
return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
```

I'm thinking I will have to create a css file with a different name and then rename it after, but I'm wondering if webpack has a non-hacky way of choosing what to export when we use an array? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an array as the value of an entry, the last element is what is exported by the bundle produced for that entry.

So move your JS files to the end of their respective entry array:

```
entry: {
  'someExportName': ['./src/themes/default.less', './src/index.js'],
  'someExportName.nonDefaultTheme': './src/themes/nonDefaultTheme.less',
}
```

Comment: Thanks sounds like it makes sense but unfortunately I have the same result

Comment: I'll mark this as correct in case it works for others, otherwise they can refer to my answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like @sdgluck's answer should work, indeed I found it written here too - https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/1703

Sadly no luck for me. What I've done is for the CSS file which has to have the same name, I imported that into `./src/index.js` so that in combination with `MiniCssExtractPlugin` a css file with the same name is created and I can avoid using the array.